# How to download dataset from amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dataset

I am trying to get the  large dataset of around 1GB and I mostly found that the large dataset are in amazon web service like 
https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/google-books-ngrams/
and states that data is available

s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/

Now I am trying to download this data. so for this purpose I created my virtual machine in AWS. how can I download this 2 gb data in my AWS so that later I could transfer to my local machine through scp??

Comment: Those files are on S3. There was no need to create server on AWS just to download those. Install the AWS CLI tool and download them with that.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark B commented, you don't need to spin up a server in AWS to download these data sets. They are publicly hosted in S3, so you can use the AWS S3 CLI's `cp` tool to download them to your local machine, by running:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/ local
```

Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).