# Download YFCC-100M dataset

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I need to download Flicker YFCC-100M dataset. I have amazon AWS account but could not figure out way to download dataset. 
[There is blog but it is not clear for me to download the dataset](http://code.flickr.net/2014/10/15/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-yahoo-flickr-100-million-creative-commons-dataset/.)

With [flicker API](https://github.com/alexis-mignon/python-flickr-api/), I can download images but that will not be YFCC100M.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058944/how-to-download-dataset-from-amazon-aws) is one suggestion but awscli could not installed on my system.

```
>> sudo apt install awscli 
>> .......... 
>> Error: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there any easy way to get this dataset downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you already have pip and either Python 2.6.5+ or Python 3.3+ installed on your system. If you want to install awscli, you'll need to run

`pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

You can read more about installing the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html).

In addition, i think [this link](https://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=i&did=67) would let you gain access to the dataset that you are looking for.

Comment: 1. awscli installed from aws github

2. I have got dataset status approved on your provided link long ago. In the status it say to download from AWS. 

"I3 - Yahoo Flickr Creative Commons 100M (14G) (Hosted on AWS)
 12/28/2017 Download from AWS"


but can't find way to download dataset from AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register on the [Yahoo Webscope website](https://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=i&did=67) and add this dataset to the "Cart".
After submitting your request for the dataset, you should receive an email with instructions. I am reproducing a part of this email, after scrubbing out some of the details and privileged information.

> 1. Download and install s3cmd from http://s3tools.org/download (or using an appropriate package manager for your platform)
> 2. Run 's3cmd --configure' and enter your access key and secret ( available via **XXXXXXXX** <-- *the actual link will be in their email*
>      ). Here you can also specify additional options, such as enabling
>      encryption during transfer, and enabling a proxy.
> 3. Run 's3cmd ls s3://yahoo-webscope/**XXXXXXX**/' to view the S3 objects for I3 - Yahoo Flickr Creative Commons 100M (14G) (Hosted on AWS)
> 4. Run 's3cmd get --recursive s3://yahoo-webscope/**XXXXXXX**/' to download a local copy of I3 - Yahoo Flickr Creative Commons 100M (14G)
>      (Hosted on AWS)

It should be easy for you to follow these steps and get the dataset. I agree, the steps are not very transparent in their website!

Comment: Does the dataset still exist on the Yahoo website? I can't find it there...